# How to pull Line Item & leave blank when there might be nothing there from Cystal Reports XI?

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, report

So I am looking to pull some information from a database, but sometimes the line item may have a Description and sometimes it does not, and when it does not, the record does not exist.

I have tried to use a left outer join to pull everything that matches my criteria and even when the Description is blank because I want to see the other information and keep that blank, but it does not seem to be working.

Any ideas?  Can I use an 'If' 'Then' statement to pull the blank fields and still have the rest of that line item get pulled as well?

Comment: Are item number and description in separate tables?

Comment: Yes they are.  More specifically, I'm using Made 2 Manage system and I want to pull the beginning material description, but for stock items it does not have a beginning material, just a finished material, what we sell, and should be blank but pull the rest of the information.  Any ideas?

Comment: On what field(s) are you linking the tables?

Comment: Quote Number and FinNumber

Answer (score 0):

Judging from what you have described, I think your best bet will be to use a subreport. Put your items in the main report and then get the description out by using a subreport.

Comment: How will that allow me to pull the blank Description and the other information for the line item?

Comment: The subreport will allow you to link fields from the subreport to the main report which will help you to get all the information for the line item and then the description through the subreport.